# fs.existsSync false positive result

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-fs

I'm working on a relatively simple node app and using fs to help write files and folders.
One of checks I need to do is see if a folder already exists, and it does, stop as I don't want to overwrite others.

I wrote a small function to check if the folder exists, but for every folder I give it, it always says it does exists, even when it does not.

```js
checkFolder: function(folder) {
        try {
            fs.existsSync(folder);
            return true;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Folder does not exists')
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And the folder path I'm passing is set via a varabiable and the `fdfdfd` is the fake folder which does not exists, but the function is reporting it does.

```js
let dialoguePath = path.join(process.cwd(), process.env.aemRepo, process.env.dialogueFolder, answers.componentName)
// /home/sga/media/dev/Work/omitted/Adobe/AEM/Projects/omitted/ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/q/components/fdfdfd
libs.checkFolder(dialoguePath)
```

I'm sure it's something stupid simple, but about to step out for a few hours so thought another set of eyes would spot my mistake.

Thanks!

Comment: where is the `if` part?

Comment: [existsSync](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v19.x/api/fs.html#fsexistssyncpath) returns a boolean

Comment: Thanks @Rudie, I was over complicating it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`existSync` [returns a boolean](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsexistssyncpath) therefore:

```
checkFolder: function(folder) {
   return fs.existsSync(folder);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @cyberwombat, reading a previous comment and seeing this, I was indeed doing stupid stuff and over complicating it.